# Configure dependency injection for xml beans in Grails 3 project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, grails, groovy

I have a project in grails 3, that has a project spring dependency, in the spring project, xml beans are configured. How should import the bens in grails architecture?

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile (project(':spring-project')) { transitive = false }
}
```

settings.gradle

```
includeFlat 'spring-project'
```

I tried the following ways:

in the resources.groovy load the beans:

```
beans = {
  importBeans('path/to/beans-definition.xml')
}
```

in the resources.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <import resource="path/to/beans-definition.xml" />

</beans>
```

Besides that, in the spring project, beans using java annotation are configured. The beans is not working in grails app, even by setting the spring project packages in the conponent scan.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["package.spring.project.beans"])
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
     static void main(String[] args) {
          GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
     }
}
```

But, nothing works. Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: are you sure, your `'path/to/beans-definition.xml'` can be found? I see no other issues

Comment: @injecteer yes, i'm using the classpath to load xml beans, but the dependency injection not working..

Answer (score 0):

Beans can also be configured using a grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml. In earlier versions of Grails this file was automatically generated for you by the run-app script, but the DSL in resources.groovy is the preferred approach now so it isn’t automatically generated now. But it is still supported - you just need to create it yourself.

```
<bean id="myBean" class="my.company.MyBeanImpl">
<property name="someProperty" value="42" />
<property name="otherProperty" value="blue" />
```

further check this [link](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/spring.html)

Comment: i used this link as reference to configure beans, but the dependency injection not working..